# How to align a TextView just below an ImageView in a GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, textview

I was trying to align a TextView just below the ImageView, but it's not working.
It aligns to the right of the ImageView.

This is what I did.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to give orientation vertical in linear layout

Comment: You don't need the ImageView and the LinearLayout. Put the image inside the TextView as a **compound drawable**. Saving on Views and ViewGroups (and also nested ones!) will boost your app performances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juts add attribute `android:orientation="vertical"` to your `LinearLayout` to show `TextView` under `ImageView`.

If you want to show `TextView` at bottom `center` position then add attribute `android:layout_gravity="center"` to `TextView`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Android">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ImageView and the LinearLayout.
Put the image inside the TextView as a **compound drawable**.

Saving on Views and ViewGroups (and also nested ones!) will boost your app performances.

This how to replace your whole layout with a much lighter version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image_here"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
```

Here a single TextView holds both the image (on top) and the text (on bottom).
Without having to use any other useless Views/ViewGroups. Therefore, speeding up your GridView.

Comment: `drawableTop` creating pivot role here

Answer (score 0):

if you can make your `LinearLayout` `RelativeLayout` then in your text view

```
<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_image"
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
```

I think it should work.